Angular Material update to v15 when using webpack v5
I am in the process of upgrading Angular from 12 to 15 and webpack 4 to 5. Everything works functionally but because of the Angular material update to MDC components, I am seeing a lot of styling issues. Because my project does not use angular-cli and only uses webpack, I cannot run the material migration tool.
I have gone through the Angular migration guide and changed all the .mat components to .mat-mdc-. This fixed some of the styling issues but some theming and spacing issues still exist. The migration guide assumes that you can run the material migration command and thus isn't very useful. What are some good sources that I could refer to while I make this upgrade manually. If someone has already made an upgrade, what were the steps you followed?
